# Proper use of "or" in the search

Tags: support, search

I studied the search capabilities of Stack Overflow and noticed an interesting phenomenon. When I'm searching for "something [c#] or [wpf]", I get the correct result (
"results found containing
something
tagged with
c# or wpf ")

When I do a little different query ("something [c#] or [wpf] or [.Net]"), I get a strange result (
"results found containing
something [c#]
tagged with
c# or wpf or .net ")
instead of the expected
"results found containing
something
tagged with
c# or wpf or .net "

The question is how to make such a request for three or more tags, with the operator "or".

Comment: @Matt You are right. Thanks!